# matrix as 2d pointer C

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, 2d

I have a 2d pointer and i use it as a matrix. For every line full of even numbers i want to add another line that will have the sum of elements.
for ex:

initial

```
 1  1  1

12 14 16

 3  3  3
```

final

```
 1  1  1

12 14 16

 3  5  7

 3  3  3
```

i have the following code and i think i have a shifting error can somedoy give me some sugestions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int suma(int x)     //sum function
{
    int s = 0, r = 0;
    while (x != 0)
    {
        r = x % 10;
        s = s + r;
        x = x / 10;
    }
    return x;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i, j, n, m, p, q, ii, **a, par = 0,r;
    printf("nr de rows\n");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    printf("columns\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    a = (int**)malloc(m*sizeof(int*));
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        a[i] = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    }
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("a[%d][%d]=", i + 1, j + 1);
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n\n\nmatricea initiala\n");    //initial matrix
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (a[i][j] % 2 == 0)
            {
                par++;
            }
            else
            {
                par = 0;
            }
        }
        if (par == n)
        {
            m++;
            a = (int**)realloc(a, m*sizeof(int*));
            a[m] = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
            for (p = m; p >i; p--)
            {
                for (q = 0; q < n; q++)
                {
                    a[p][q] = a[p - 1][q];
                }
            }
            par = 0;
            for (r = 0; r < n; r++)
            {
                a[i + 1][r] = suma(a[i][r]);
            }
            i--;
        }
        par = 0;
    }
    printf("\nmat finala\n");       //final matrix
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fix point:

1.`return x;` --> `return s;`
 2.`for (i = 0; i < m; i++)` --> `for (i = m-1; i >= 0; --i)` : The process from the bottom to the top
 3.at after realloc, `a[m] = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));` --> `a[m-1] = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));`  : a[m] is out of bounds.
 4.`for (p = m; p >i; p--)` --> `for (p = m-1; p >i+1; p--)`
 5.`i--;` --> `//i--;` : It is no longer needed.

Comment: It is only just redundant. Not a mistake.

Comment: @ryyker Where does it is written in the standard?

Comment: It works , but can give so aditional info on 2 3 and 4.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY it is not recommended because it hides a compiler warning when you forget to include stdlib. See http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html. It is a good suggestion, but I understand if you were trying to follow the code in the question.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Think of the case where the matrix has one row with the contents 0, 0. Not sure what the intended behavior is, but your suggested implementation would go into an infinite loop, continually making and processing new rows with 0, 0. To solve this, #5 should be i++ to effectively skip over the added "sum row".

Comment: @AlexPogue Infinite repetition is not.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Infinite repetition is not what? Are you saying your implementation does not have an infinite loop?

Comment: Discussion about the cast is not required. Assumption of the story does not need. It will try again if it is a mistake.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY My bad, I didn't read #2 close enough. Bottom-to-top processing avoids the issue.